# How can I display an SVG containing other SVGs in an image viewer? (An SVG containing image with href to another image)

Tags: image-viewers, svg

I'm unable to get any image viewers to display SVG files that have an `image` or `use` with an `href` attribute, that points to another SVG file.

I can view it in a browser, but **I'm looking for an image viewer to display the SVG (with embedded images) that can automatically refresh** as I make changes.  A VSCode extension would be better but I'm perfectly happy if any image viewer can do this.

Try this, create a test.svg,

```xml
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image href="test_embed_this.svg" height="200" width="200"/>
</svg>
```

Create the test_embed_this.svg,

```xml
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Now try viewing test.svg.   I have tried the default Image Viewer, and Geeqie, and Inkscape. None of them are able to display the test.svg properly.  Browsers do it just fine.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04

They all show similar to this

[image]

Comment: eog (Image Viewer) displays the red circle through test.svg on Ubuntu 21.10. Inkscape 1.1 does not.

Comment: @vanadium interesting! I haven't tried 21.10. I wonder if there's some limitation in the specific version I have. Can you share your version? Mine is Image Viewer 3.36.3

Comment: In 21.10 it will be 3.40. Likely a feature update.